# C# regular expression match

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to have a Regex which will match a separating comma phrases 
of equal amount of opening and closing brackets of the same type between a comma.

for example...

```
{abc} (def), [ghi], (jkl, mno)
-----------------------------
the match should be:

{abc} (def)  
[ghi]  
(jkl, mno)
```

I'm working with C# .Net

thanks for advance!

Comment: imo it would be better to write a parsing function.

Comment: A regex is a poor choice here, what you want is a simple state machine parser.

Comment: I fear that phrases with nested brackets are a CFG (Chomsky 2) and regex is regular (Chomsky 3) (hence the REGex). You cannot parse a CFG with a regular grammar.

Comment: Is the number of items (on each line) limited in any way?

Comment: @Hyperboreus: .NET regexes are not limited by such feeble theory!

Comment: Will brackets ever be nested?  That is, could a valid string contain things like `(x(y)z)` or `[a{b}c]`?

Comment: @Porges Then, oh dedicated reader, they are no regex. But this will lead again to a religious debate. Next step will be to parse XML with regex and He w҉̵̞̟̠̖̗̘̙̜̝̞̟̠͇̊̋̌̍̎̏̐̑̒̓̔̊̋̌̍̎̏̐̑̒̓̔̿̿̿̕̚̕̚͡ ̒̓̔̕̚ho Waits Behind ҉̵̞̟̠̖̗̘̙̜̝̞̟̠͇̊̋̌̍̎̏̐̑̒̓̔̊̋̌̍̎̏̐̑̒̓̔̿̿̿̕̚̕̚͡ ̒̓̔̕̚The Wall. ҉̵̞̟̠̖̗̘̙̜̝̞̟̠͇̊̋̌̍̎̏̐̑̒̓̔̊̋̌̍̎̏̐̑̒̓̔̿̿̿̕̚̕̚͡ ̒̓̔̕̚ ҉̵̞̟̠̖̗̘̙̜̝̞̟̠͇̊̋̌̍̎̏̐̑̒̓̔̊̋̌̍̎̏̐̑̒̓̔̿̿̿̕̚̕̚ ͡ ̒̓̔̕̚,

Answer (score 3):

If there are no nested brackets, you could use:

```
((?:\{[^}]*\}|\([^)]*\)|\[[^\]]*\])\s*)+

string test  = "{abc} (def), [ghi], (jkl, mno)";
string pattern = @"((?:\{[^}]*\}|\([^)]*\)|\[[^\]]*\])\s*)+";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(test, pattern))
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

This prints:

```
{abc} (def)
[ghi]
(jkl, mno)
```

Comment: The OP actually asked how to split on commas that aren't enclosed in brackets, but this is definitely a better approach.

Comment: Thanks, and it's true that pattern doesn't require that the sequences be separated by commas.  OP, if comma delimination is important, you could use the alternate pattern `(?<=^|,\s*)((?:\{[^}]*\}|\([^)]*\)|\[[^\]]*\])\s*)+(?=\s*(?:,|$))`, which returns the same output.

Comment: I was really making a general observation.  People tend to fixate on `Split()` because that's they're doing, splitting, right?  But in cases like this where the required split regex turns out to be ridiculously complex, a `Matches()` approach is usually much easier to implement.